# install CMake package on windows visual studio problem (find_package)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, installation, cmake, glfw

I made a simple program using glfw in Linux. and I want to build it in windows now. 
when I install glfw in Linux, I did the following steps.

1. install CMake.
2. download glfw source code.
3. create a build folder in the source code folder.
4. do "cmake ../" in the build folder
5. do "make"
6. do "make install"

Then in CMakeLists.txt file:

```
find_package( glfw3 3.3 REQUIRED )

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main glfw)
```

in source code:

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

//use glfw
```

So I want to do the same thing in windows visual studio.
I did the following steps.

1. install CMake
2. download glfw source file.
3. create a build folder in the source code folder.
4. do "cmake ../" in the build folder
5. go to build folder, open GLFW project in visual studio using Administrator rights.
6. build ALL_BUILD in visual studio.

As a result, I got C:\Program Files (x86)\GLFW folder. there is include, lib, config files. 
And then I created a new CMake project.

CMake File:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\Program Files (x86)\GLFW\lib\cmake\glfw3")

find_package( glfw3 3.3 REQUIRED )

include_directories( "C:\Program Files (x86)\GLFW" )

project ("glfw_test")

add_executable (glfw_test "glfw_test.cpp" "glfw_test.h")
```

And error message saying:

```
CMake Error at C:\Users\home\source\repos\glfw_test\CMakeLists.txt:3 (set):
  Syntax error in CMake code at

    C:/Users/home/source/repos/glfw_test/CMakeLists.txt:3

  when parsing string

    C:\Program Files (x86)\GLFW\lib\cmake\glfw3

  Invalid character escape '\P'.    glfw_test   C:\Users\home\source\repos\glfw_test\CMakeLists.txt 3
```

Questions.

1. Why does include, lib files are installed directly in program files (x86)?
2. How can I do "make install" in windows?

Comment: You will have to use / as the path separator instead of \ or escape the path like you do in c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR answers:

1. Because you did not specified an installation prefix.
   Add `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to your GLFW CMake command, e.g.

`cmake -S <sourcedir> -B <builddir> -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PRFIX=<yourinstalldir>`

2. `cmake --build <builddir> --target install --config Release`

If you do not specify an installation prefix to your cmake command on Windows it is set to `C:\Program Files (x86)` for 32bit builds and to `C:\Program Files` for 64bit builds.

Do not hardcode `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` into your `CMakeLists.txt`. Explicitly specify what generator and architecture you want to use for your build. Add it to your CMake command line as argument, e.g.

`cmake -S <sourcedir> -B <builddir> -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A Win32 -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=<yourglfwrootinstalldir>`

And your CMakeLists.txt file should look as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
project ("glfw_test")

find_package( glfw3 3.3 REQUIRED )
add_executable (glfw_test glfw_test.cpp glfw_test.h)
target_link_libraries(glfw_test PRIVATE glfw)
```